# A menu which can be triggered by code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am trying to make a menu in javascript/JQuery (css is also an option) that allows me to make it do things like show a particular drop down menu, activate a button in the menu and mimic mouseover effects without the mouse actually doing any of these things.

The reason for this is that I am making an interface that uses a function similar to let me google that for you, meaning an image of a mouse moving on the screen "showing" you where to find things in the menu. Therefore I need to be able to code in things to make a particular menu button pretend to have mouseover or having been clicked.

So basicly, how do I make a menu with unique identifiers for each button that can be called for desired effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make all of your event handlers stand alone functions you can call them manually as well. For example, instead of registering an anonymous click handler like so:

```
$('#myelement').click(function(){ /* do stuff */ });
```

You would have:

```
function doStuff() { /* do stuff */ }

$('#myelement').click(doStuff);

// somewhere else in your code
doStuff();
```

Alternatively, if you are using jQuery, you can just call `$('#myelement').click()` somewhere else in your code, and it will call whatever onclick handlers are attached to the element, the same as if someone had physically clicked on it.

Comment: You can also make use of .trigger() [JQuery Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), but you don't necessarily have to trigger the actual events, you can mimic the affects of the events using .css() [JQuery Css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) by only triggering one event.

Comment: Yeah, so far I am using .trigger() but the problem is that with trigger, I have no idea as to what I should attach the trigger function to to make it work, as the menu buttons have no unique identificators I can use, and using the id="" doesn't work either... so in the example above I do not know what I should replace #myelement with, as the meny doesn't work like that, it is not composed of elements for each button.

Comment: Well, I try, but it won't react to it... it doesn't answer to it's identifier

Comment: Can you post an example of your menu markup, perhaps on jsFiddle?

Comment: Ah! nevermind! found a syntax error now that solved it, using your method. Thank you so much!